# Importing Bootstrap JavaScript to vanilla project

Tags: javascript, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap v5.2.3 and trying to add the JavaScript bundle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Big project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container py-4 px-3 mx-auto">
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is how my style.scss code looks like.

```
// 1. Include functions first (so you can manipulate colors, SVGs, calc, etc)
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";

// 2. Include any default variable overrides here

// 3. Include remainder of required Bootstrap stylesheets (including any separate color mode stylesheets)
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";

// 4. Include any default map overrides here

// 5. Include remainder of required parts
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";

// 6. Optionally include any other parts as needed
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/helpers";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/buttons";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/navbar";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/nav";

// 7. Optionally include utilities API last to generate classes based on the Sass map in `_utilities.scss`
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";
```

I see that bootstrap.bundle.min.js is being loaded over the network, but the modal does not work properly. As far as I informed myself, in v5+ there is no need to add jQuery or Popperjs

Do you have any idea what am I missing here?

I have tried also typescript import statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` file will include `bootstrap` and `popper` js. But it will not have `bootstrap.min.css` file which is require your bootstrap design to work properly. Also, modal popup to work you need to have a button, onclick so you can open it.

Working sample from your code also look at [Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/) documentation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Big project</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous"> <!-- Added this -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container py-4 px-3 mx-auto">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"> <!-- Added this -->
      Launch demo modal
    </button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the info @Gajjar! This already helped. In the styles.css I have 
`@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root"; etc...`
I wonder what is the difference. And nav still does not expand ... Do you have any idea why?

Comment: With your given code you have not added a button that triggers the modal to open and also it doesn't have a nav so I can't check what is wrong.

Comment: Actually replacing the style.scss with the CDN styles solved my problem, but I wonder what is the difference with the scss imports I mentioned above?

Comment: here is my style.scss https://stackoverflow.com/a/75776265/6725880

Comment: Add your styles.scss as the question instead of adding it as the answer. Also, you are showing `style.scss` and you have added `style.css` in your HTML. Which framework are you using react/angular? In your `style.scss` add `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';`

Comment: Well, the scss is compiled to css using gulp sass.